# How to use full-string conditionals in latex

Tags: macros, tex-core, conditionals

I want some conditional paragraphs in my document.  I've been following chapter 13.2 of ["Tex by Topic"](https://ftp.snt.utwente.nl/pub/software/tex/info/texbytopic/TeXbyTopic.pdf), but I've run into limitations.

```
\documentClass{report}

\def\option{a}

\begin{document}

\if\option a
  This is a paragraph related to option A
\fi

\end{document}
```

However, the values for my options are limited to one character.  How can I use `\if` to match a multi-character string?  I tried a few things below, but I'm never able to get it to match

```
\documentClass{report}

\def\brand{toyota}

\begin{document}

\if\brand toyota
  This paragraph is specific to toyota
\else \if\brand{volvo}
  This paragraph is specific to volvo
\else
  This paragraph is generic
\fi

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try it like this:

```
\documentclass{report}

\def\brand{toyota}
\def\brandToyota{toyota}
\def\brandVolvo{volvo}
\begin{document}

\ifx\brand\brandToyota
  This paragraph is specific to toyota
\else \ifx\brand\brandVolvo
  This paragraph is specific to volvo
\else
  This paragraph is generic
\fi
\fi

\end{document}
```

`\ifx` just compares after expanding the commands and this does the trick.

Comment: This is much more legible.  It's exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: Glad about this. Happy TeXing @Stewart!

Answer (score 5):

You can use a string switch:

```
\documentclass{article}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\stringswitch}{mmm}
 {
  \str_case_e:nnF { #1 } { #2 } { #3 }
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\newcommand{\brand}{toyota}

\begin{document}

\stringswitch{\brand}{
  {toyota}{This paragraph is specific to toyota}
  {volvo}{This paragraph is specific to volvo}
}{This paragraph is generic}

\renewcommand{\brand}{volvo}

\stringswitch{\brand}{
  {toyota}{This paragraph is specific to toyota}
  {volvo}{This paragraph is specific to volvo}
}{This paragraph is generic}

\renewcommand{\brand}{cadillac}

\stringswitch{\brand}{
  {toyota}{This paragraph is specific to toyota}
  {volvo}{This paragraph is specific to volvo}
}{This paragraph is generic}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

You can use `\ifdefstring` from `etoolbox`:

```
\documentClass{report}

\def\brand{toyota}

\begin{document}

\ifdefstring{\brand}{toyota}{
  This paragraph is for Toyota owners
}{\ifdefstring{\brand}{volvo}{
  If you're a Volvo owner, you'll want to read this paragraph.
}{
  This paragraph is for everyone else
}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you insist in using `\if`, David Kastrup's `\if\strequal...`-test might be of interest.

(Modifying the code below so that instead of `\def` LaTeX's defining-commands are used and no nameclashes with macros of packages like etoolbox occur might be a nice homework.)

Compile the following example using (plain) TeX, not LaTeX.

```tex
%%======================================================================
%% Expandable comparison of two strings:
%%
%% David Kastrup's \if\strequal-test from the
%% TeX Pearl Diving Site;
%% Pearls of 2005;
%% Title: David Kastrup - Comparing two strings known to consist
%% only of characters ;
%% Url: <http://www.gust.org.pl/projects/pearls/2005p/david-kastrup/bachotex2005-david-kastrup-pearl1.pdf>
%%----------------------------------------------------------------------
%% Usage:
%%   \if\strequal{junk}{#1}true\else false\fi
%% will be true for #1 being “junk”, and false otherwise
%%......................................................................
\def\strequal#1{\number\strequalstart{}{}#1\relax}%
\def\strequalstart#1#2#3{\if#3\relax\strequalstop\fi\strequalstart{\if#3#1}{#2\fi}}%
\def\strequalstop\fi\strequalstart#1#2#3{\fi#1#3\relax'#213 }%
%%======================================================================
%% Expandable comparison of two strings known to expand to characters
%% only; \strcmp
%% - expands strings via \csname..\endcsname and applies \string
%% - and replaces explicit space tokens with category-12 space tokens, 
%% - then does David Kastrup's \strequal-test.
%%----------------------------------------------------------------------
%% Usage:
%%   \if\strcmp{ju nk}{#1}true\else false\fi
%% will be true for #1 expanding “ju nk”, and false otherwise
%%......................................................................
\def\strfot#1#2{#1}\def\strsot#1#2{#2}\long\def\strexchg#1#2{#2{#1}}%
\long\def\strmakecstoken#1{%
  \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\strexchg
  \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter{\expandafter\string\csname #1\endcsname}%
}%
\def\strspacereplace#1{%
  \if\relax\strgobbletospace#1 \relax\expandafter\strfot\else\expandafter\strsot\fi
  {\strexchg{#1}}{\expandafter\strspacereplace\expandafter{\strdorepl#1}}%
}%
\def\strgobbletospace#1 {}%
\begingroup
\def\strdorepl#1{\endgroup\def\strdorepl##1 {##1#1}}%
\catcode`\ =12\relax
\strdorepl{ }%
\long\def\strcmp#1#2{%
  \strmakecstoken{#2}{\strspacereplace}%
  {\strmakecstoken{#1}{\strspacereplace}{\strequal}}%
}%

%%======================================================================

\def\brand{toyota}
%\def\brand{vol vo}
%\def\brand{generic}

This paragraph is 
\if\strcmp{\brand}{toyota}%
  specific to toyota%
\else 
  \if\strcmp{\brand}{vol vo}%
    specific to volvo%
  \else
    generic%
  \fi
\fi
.

\bye
```